# Действие при selected елемента GridView

Tags: android

**Стоит задача выполнять соответствующее действие в зависимости от того, на какой item в GridView нажал пользователь, но еще его не отпустил.**

*То есть при selected*. По этому я использую:

```
gridView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Log.d(LOG, ((TaskName)gridView.getAdapter().getItem(i)).getTaskName());
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
```

По идеи при нажатии на item, но до того как его отпустить, должен напечататься лог! **Но почему то не печатается!**

**Такой у меня адаптер:**

```
public class GridViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<TaskName>{

    private AppCompatActivity context;
    private TextView nameView, countView;
    private TaskName taskName;
    public GridViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<TaskName> taskNames){
        super(context, 0 , taskNames);
        this.context = (AppCompatActivity) context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null){
            convertView = context.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.grid_view_item, null);
        }

        taskName = getItem(position);
        nameView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.task_name);
        nameView.setText(taskName.getTaskName());
        countView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.count_task);
        countView.setText(String.valueOf(taskName.getTaskNameId()));
      return convertView;
    }


}
```

**Если можно, подскажите в чем ошибка ?**

Comment: Попробуйте повесить слушатель нажатий в адаптере, а не на gridView.

Comment: По моему опыту внешние слушатели плохо работают при нестандартной разметке. И неизвестно как именно работает onSelected слушатель. Думаю, вам надо поробовать повесить onTouch и в нём реагировать на ACTION_DOWN

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, его вешать на что ?? На отдельный элемент GridView или на GridView ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрел исходники. `OnItemSelected` вызывается только если с клавиатуры выделение перевести на элемент. Пальцем этого добиться нельзя.

Для того чтобы поймать нажатие на элемент без его отпускания можно попробовать на вид элемента повесить обработчик onTouch:

```
v.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent ev) {
        final int action = ev.getAction();
        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            // ....
            return true; // Если также хотим получить остальные события (MOVE/UP)
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: и потом сделать реализацию setOnItemSelectedListener() ?

Comment: Да, должно помочь. По крайней мере у меня проблем с setOnItemSelectedListener при любых вариантах разметки не было. Единственно я не очень уверен, что обработчик будет вызываться до поднятия пальца с экрана.

Comment: сделал так как вы написали! Но результата нет: нажимаю на элемент лог не выводится, отпускаю - тоже не выводиться (

Comment: А в разметке есть clickable элементы ?

Comment: Оп. Только сейчас заметил. У меня именно selected версия так нормально и не заработала. Я везде использую setOnItemClickListener

Comment: Добавил в ответ. Надо проверить, что сам список имеет аттрибут clickable=true

Comment: добавил clickable=true  для GridView! Изменений нет никаких (

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37215/discussion-between---and-vitaliy).

Comment: Я извиняюсь, что  отвлекаю вас! Этот метод работает, как надо,  но почему то, где бы я не нажимал - выводится текст первого элемента!

Comment: Мне кажется это надо уже в новый вопрос. И привести код. Либо как вариант в чате куски кода запостить.